# Maximum bounding box of a shape from one AffineTransform to another

Tags: java, math, image-processing, geometry, interpolation

## Summary

I'm trying to find the bounding box of a shape that is transformed between to transformation anchors. The goal is to encapsulate an animation of a rectangle so that none of the rectangle is ever outside the rendered area. I am using these three java classes:

- java.awt.Rectangle
- java.awt.geom.AffineTransform
- Anchor (custom class)

## Currently What I Have

Here's how the anchor class is defined:

```
public class Anchor {
  public double deltaX = 0, deltaY = 0;
  public double scaleX = 1, scaleY = 1;
  public double degrees = 0;
}
```

In my real application, I have a set of anchors that are attached to a time, and as the animation progresses the shape is interpolated between the two neighboring "Anchors." But for this question we only need to worry about 2 Anchors.

Here's a crude, mostly working implementation of what I want, but I feel like there must be a more accurate, efficient mathematical approach. It's sloooooow thanks to having to make many steps. The more steps I iterate through, the better results, obviously.

```
public static Rectangle getBounds(Anchor leftAnchor, Anchor rightAnchor, int shapeWidth, int shapeHeight) {
  Rectangle baseShape = new Rectangle(0, 0, shapeWidth, shapeHeight); // the shape we draw in the animation
  Rectangle globalBounds = null, localBounds; // global bounds is the bounds of the whole animation
  for(double time = 0;time <= 1;time += 0.001) { // interpolate from one anchor to the next (1000 steps)
    // Create the transformation and find the finds of the resultant shape
    AffineTransform transformation = getInterpolatedTransformation(leftAnchor, rightAnchor, shapeWidth, shapeHeight, time);
    localBounds = transformation.createTransformedShape(baseShape).getBounds();
    if(globalBounds == null) // if it's the first step, create the initial bounds
      globalBounds = localBounds;
    else // otherwise continue adding bounds
      globalBounds.add(localBounds);
  }
  return globalBounds; // return the global bounds
}

public static AffineTransform getInterpolatedTransformation(Anchor left, Anchor right, int width, int height, double time) {
  // get the interpolated values from the two anchors
  double deltaX = linearInterpolation(left.deltaX, right.deltaX, time);
  double deltaY = linearInterpolation(left.deltaX, right.deltaX, time);
  double scaleX = linearInterpolation(left.scaleX, right.scaleX, time);
  double scaleY = linearInterpolation(left.scaleY, right.scaleY, time);
  double degrees = linearInterpolation(left.degrees, right.degrees, time);

  // Create the AffineTransformation based on the two interpolated acnhors
  AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
  transform.translate(deltaX, deltaY);
  transform.scale(scaleX, scaleY);
  transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees),
          scaleX*width/2.0+deltaX,
          scaleY*height/2.0+deltaY);

  return transform; // return it
}
```

## The Big Question

Is there an efficient way to find the bounding box that contains every possible transformation of a rectangle that is interpolated between two Affine Transformations.

### Notes

Originally my animation anchors did not have a degree defined. I could find the bounding box by simply adding the resulting bounding box of the left anchor's AffineTransform and the right anchor's AffineTransform. However, with rotation the points of the animated rectangle can escape these more easily found bounding boxes.

PS: To you C programmers, I apologise for my verboseness in my code...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the goal is. Do you want to find the maximum bounding box that a Shape *may* cover? Or do you need to find the *exact* bounding box of a set of transformations? How precise does it need to be (overshoot acceptable?/undershoot acceptable?).

Comment: Yes - I want to find the maximum bounding box the shape may cover while interpolating between two Affine Transforms. The exact bounds are preferable, but overshooting isn't too big of an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had sent this Stack OVerflow to a friend for some advice.  He didn't have time to look at it then and there but he did send me this: [The X & Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). It may be possible to solve this math question, but I found a much better way to go about the solution.

I knew how many frames the animation would take place over (generating a GIF) so I was able to simply pre-calculate each frames' transformation - find the bounding box of all frames and then generate the output image correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From your iterative solution you could derive a one-step solution (it may overestimate the bounding box though, since this will calculate the maximum area covered possible if the most extreme values for rotation were chosen):

```
public static Rectangle getBounds(Anchor leftAnchor, Anchor rightAnchor, int shapeWidth, int shapeHeight) {
   double size = Math.sqrt((shapeWidth * shapeWidth) + (shapeHeight * shapeHeight));
   // find the maximum scale
   double maxScale = Math.max(leftAnchor.scaleX, leftAnchor.scaleY);
   maxScale = Math.max(rightAnchor.scaleX);    
   maxScale = Math.max(rightAnchor.scaleY);    
   int maxSize = (int) Math.ceil(maxScale * size);
   return new Rectangle(0, 0, maxSize, maxSize);
}
```

This works using the assumtion that the original Shape can not cover anything outside a circle described by the diagonal of the original rectangle - no matter how you rotate it, it won't leave the circle. By finding the maximum applied scale, the circle is adjusted for scaling.

Comment: It's a good idea. I think I see what you're doing (but there are some bugs in your code). It may be the way I have to go.

Answer (score 0):

By convexity, the bounding box of a rectangle is the same as the bounding box of its four corners. So you can reason on the bounding box of a single corner and then "merge" the results of the four corners.

When you apply your transformation on a corner, you simultaneously change the center, the size and the orientation. In other words, the trajectory is complicated curve, a deformed Archimedean spiral.

An easy way is to find an approximate bounding box by computing a number of positions in the given time interval and keep the extremes (ideally for every frame, given your frame rate).

The rigourous way is by finding the extrema of the curve, analytically.

Taking a look at the transformed abscissa, we have `X = X0 + t.DX + (Sx + t.DSx) cos(A+t.Da) - (Sy + t.DSy) sin(A+t.Da)`.

Derive once and find the zeroes of the derivative: `0 = DX + DSx cos(A+t.Da) - Da.(Sx + t.DSx) sin(A+t.Da) - DSy sin(A+t.Da) - Da.(Sy+t.DSy) cos(A+t.Da)`.

This is unfortunately a transcendent equation, as it has terms of the form `t.sin(t)` and similar, so an analytical solution is not possible and you'll have to resort to numerical approaches.

My recommendation for a compromise between computational cost and accuracy: compute the corner positions for a reasonable number of frames, and keep the extreme values of `Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, Ymax`.
If you observe a change in behavior on one of the bounds, say `Xmin` decreasing then increasing, you can refine the search by using a smaller step (until you get to a step of a single frame); alternatively, use the three values around the minimum and perform parabolic interpolation.

UPDATE:

The case with a constant scale can be treated analytically. (Either the scale is really constant, or you stay on the safe side by keeping the maximum value of the scale).

For instance the equation for the abscissa has a form like `A + B.t + C.cos(t) + D.sin(t)`. Deriving, `0 = B - C.sin(t) + D.cos(t)`.  This is a well-known linear trigonometric equation. You can find its roots in the time interval. A careful discussion is needed.

Comment: If you don't change all parameters simultaneously, two cases are tractable. Without a change in the rotation, the trajectory is a line segment, very easy to deal with. Change of rotation alone gives a circular arc (no too difficult).